# Suspect someone as someone

Tags: word-usage

If someone thinks I'm faking my identity, trying to be someone I'm not, and claiming me to be "A" can I use:

He suspects me as A.

Is the use of "suspect as" natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, "suspects" can be a noun or a verb.

Your usage of "suspects" is correct, but it would be better for you to say:

> He suspects that I am A.
>
> He suspects me of being A.

Saying "suspects me as" could be a little unclear because it can also mean that he is doing the suspecting and he (not you) is A. In other words, "As A, he suspects me." But since that is not your intent, it's best to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Or perhaps even more common, [*He suspects me **of being** (a spy, whatever)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+suspects+me+of+being+a+spy%22) Personally, I don't think I'd consider *to suspect X as Y* to be syntactically valid in *any* context.

Comment: Actually, I can't really argue with [*(Something makes me) **suspect you as the author** (of some anonymous text or nefarious deed).*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BMYUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA223&dq=%22suspect+you+as+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirueChzZPgAhXhSRUIHRI4AOUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22suspect%20you%20as%20the%22&f=false) But it is from a couple of centuries ago. I think *suspect you **to be** the author* would be much more likely today, even if it wasn't then.

Comment: @Fum Yeah. That's why I worded the answer as "it would be better for you to say" rather than say "suspect as" is incorrect. Good research!